# Why doesn't isset in an if statement work it always passes

Tags: php

It is printing my print statement even though I haven't touched anything on the page. Without having put anything in the number box, or having pushed the submit button it seems to be running anyway, ignoring/passing the if statement.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body  style="background-color:black;color:white">


    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="bogo.php">
        Size
        <input type="number" name="size" value="" max="10000" min="1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <?php
    function foo(){
        if(isset($_POST["size"]) && isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $a = $_POST["size"];
            $i = 0;

            for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++) {
                $arr[$i] = $i;
            }

            print("Original Array: <br/>");
        }
        else {
        }
    }

    foo();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/gvYVwS cant reproduce what you describe

Comment: Add check for empty check along with isset check.

Comment: What is the version of PHP? Can't reproduce on PHP 5.6

Comment: Try printing $_POST before the condition and see what it shows. Also please post the response here

Comment: There is a function call foo().  Remove that if you want your function to be called.

Comment: @Nguaial How can the OP run the `foo()` function if it's removed? It would then be undefined and cause a Fatal Error.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible - is this your original code - the one that causes problems?

Answer (score -2):

You need to put php code outside html code.

```
<html>

</html>

<?php>

     php code 
<?>
```

Comment: nope. he doesn't.  look at where his closing html tag is.

Comment: One should put PHP code and HTML code separate but how your solution solves the current problem.

Comment: @techgyani - The problem is that php function gets called by itself.  So separating them would prevent this from happening.

Comment: i see what your saying but no it will make no difference here

Comment: Guys, where is the OP. Is he still needs support?

Comment: @nogad - You can't reproduce the problem cause there is a problem with the code. Try separate the blocks of code.

Comment: The placement of php can be anywhere on the page (obviously accounting for scope and linear processing), it's a matter of good practice to separate out business logic from view. Simply moving the php from spot on the page to another spot isn't going to fix whatever weird anomaly the OP is having.

Comment: The problem is that there is a function call `foo()`. So when the page is loaded, it will call this function automatically.  If he doesn't want it to be called, get rid of `foo()`.

Comment: Yeah but the function is using a listen condition `if(isset($_POST["size"]) && isset($_POST["submit"])){` which means it shouldn't print if the form is not submitted. According to the OP it's meeting those conditions without them submitting the form.

Comment: @Rasclatt - The $_POST[] is obviously set.  That's why it is going into if block.  He needs to clear the browser and re-do it.  If you load that page clean slate, $_POST[] should NOT have been set so it should never go into if block.

Comment: The OP states `Without having put anything in the number box, or having pushed the submit button it seems to be running anyway`...so to the OP, the `$_POST` is not *obviously* set. Bottom line, as stated by @nogad and others, your answer would make no difference.

Comment: No, that is what everyone is saying, it can not be reproduced. The code as is works as it should.